# Django database migration error

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite, migration

I have a Django project connected to Gmail API.
When I try to do database migration it returns this:

```
C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\FastProject>python manage.py migrate FastProject
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", l
ine 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", l
ine 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line
288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line
332, in execute
    self.check()
  File "C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line
364, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrat
e.py", line 58, in _run_checks
    issues.extend(super()._run_checks(**kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line
351, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line
73, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13,
in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23,
in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 397, i
n check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 36,
in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 536, i
n url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 36,
in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 529, i
n urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\FastProject\FastProject\urls.py", line 21, in <module>
    path('', include('mainApp.urls')),
  File "C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in incl
ude
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\FastProject\mainApp\urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\FastProject\mainApp\views.py", line 2, in <module>
    from quickstart import go
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'quickstart'
```

I have also tried 'makemigrations' and old one 'syncdb', but first one gives the same error and the second one isn't used anymore.I use SQLite3. This is in my settings :

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'results_db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

"quickstart" is a file from which I call a function. I guess all the names are correct, so I don't know what's the problem. This is error was before but I decided to think about it later.

Thanks.

Comment: is it your own file?

Comment: in case it is your own file, you should put it inside a folder, then add a blank `__init__.py` file in the directory, basically create it as a python package.

Comment: @Lemayzeur yes, I was connecting to Gmail API by Google guide, so all the code in that file is from Google site but file was created by myself.
And PyCharm gave me a solution to install 'quickstart' package so I have a __int__.py you are talking about. Here: https://ibb.co/fdvaRJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's definitely related to this line:

```
   File "C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\FastProject\mainApp\views.py", line 2, in <module>
    from quickstart import go
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'quickstart'
```

Looks like you're missing the `quickstart` module. Is it related to some tutorial? Maybe you forgot to activate your virtual environment?

**Update:**

You should use local imports or provide the full path to the package if you have such a project structure https://ibb.co/fdvaRJ:

```
from .quickstart import go
```

or

```
from mainApp.quickstart import go
```

Or you could put your `quickstart.py` module one level upper and just use

```
from quickstart import go
```

as you do now.

Don't forget to check out the official guide on packaging and modules in Python: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Comment: Yeah, but not the file, just the code in it. It's from Gmail API Quickstart guide. I go to views.py but "from quickstart import go"  is not even red and seemd to be ok

Comment: I think there is something wrong with the structure of your modules, you'd better check out this official guide on packaging in python, take extra attention to `__init__.py` files: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Answer (score 0):

I did some manipulations with that quickstart file. First I created in every folder '**init**.py', then I created an empty folder in app directory and drag`n`dropped there 'quickstart.py' and created there an empty "init" file too. Didn't work: the error just changed from ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'quickstart' to ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'api.quickstart'.

Then I deleted all "init" files created 2 minutes ago, put 'quickstart' file back to the root folder of my app and also drag'n'dropped an "init" file.

The error became just like " from quickstart import go
ImportError: cannot import name 'go' ". What I did next is just changed "from quickstart import go" to "import quickstart" and then called go function like "quickstart.go()"

Too much text so images for better understanding:

https://ibb.co/fdvaRJ

https://ibb.co/kzgPmJ

https://ibb.co/jyjVty